# Cannot upload an APK without the signature

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I disabled my app signing in Google Play Console, but APK upload still fails with the message:

```
You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures
```

see the screenshot:

[image]

EDIT1:

my 'Build Variations' looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select both signature versions (v1 and v2) in last step and then build the apk.

Also don't forget Build -> Clean project before.

[image]

Comment: thanks! where are these check boxes (and 'last stop')? Cannot find them under 'Build Variations'.

Comment: when you generate apk. Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/APK  and then complete the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Select both the checkboxes for signature versions (v1 and v2) in last step and then build the apk.

[In this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnvF9.png)